# Combining 2 different projects into single CMake File

Tags: c++, cmake

I have two separate projects, A and B. Both have same class names inside their `Class.cpp` files but the body of the classes are completely different both have their own CMakelists.txt structures as well. Neither depend on each other. Right now, I need to their respective folders and run the cmake command one by one. Since it is hard to version control them with seperate folders, I would like to have them inside the same folder. Like below :

```
Project
├── build (where to build)
├── CMakeLists.txt (main one)
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── ProjA
    |   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── Class.cpp
    │   └── Class.h
    ├── ProjB
    |   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── Class.cpp
    │   └── Class.h
    └── main.cpp
```

the `src/CMakeLists.txt` has the following only:

```
add_subdirectory(ProjA)
add_subdirectory(ProjB)
```

I kept the CMake files as it is from the original and only added the following to the each :
`add_executable(ProjXX EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ${SOURCE_FILE})` ( Here `XX` is replaced with the name of project respectively)

When I try to build `ProjA.exe` and `ProjB.exe` with same `main.cpp` as common for both, it only generates the `ProjA` executable. I tried to output a message and it seems like it also prints that message in `ProjB` too but it never generates the executable for B.

How could I approach this issue to solve it ?

I am trying to merge 2 same but unrelated projects from a different folders ( unrelated) to a single folder project for version control friendly

### Edit:

This is `ProjA/CMakeLists.txt` file :

```
set(SOURCE_FILE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp Class.cpp)
set(TARGET_NAME ProjA)
set(TARGET ${TARGET_NAME}.exe)
add_executable(${TARGET} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ${SOURCE_FILE})
target_include_directories(${TARGET} PRIVATE ../ProjA)
set(COMPILE_FLAGS  " -Wall -std=c++17")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CXXFLAGS}")
set_target_properties(${TARGET} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${COMPILE_FLAGS}")
```

Comment: Most likely the problem is related with subprojects and their `CMakeLists.txt`. Without knowing content of that files we simply cannot help you. Description "When I try to build `ProjA.exe` and `ProjB.exe` with same `main.cpp` as common for both" provides very vague description of that files. Please, add those `CMakeLists.txt` to the question post too.

Comment: @Tsyvarev edited to add one of the CMake files, the ProjB one is replica of it with the names updated for it

Comment: "Both have same class names inside ..." - Sounds like a perfect use case for namespaces ..

Comment: You are excluding both executables, hence there is no way for cmake to build _all excluded_ projects. Simply remove `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` and build the project using cmake with no specific target.

Comment: isn't having two classes with the same name an ODR violation? Or are they encapsulated as non-exported things in shared libraries?

Comment: How did you build the project? `cmake --build build_dir --target ProjA ProjB`???